# How to extract the values using Hashes

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I want this small piece of snippet to display the contents inside swatkats, popeye, avengers arrays however I'm unable to print it

```
    %HoA = (
    swatkats    => [ "Tbone", "Razer" ],
    popeye        => [ "Olive", "bluto", "pope" ],
    avengers       => [ "ironman", "hulk", "Blackwidow","cap"]);
    @arr=keys%HoA;
    print "$arr[0]\n";
    print "@arr[1]\n";
    print "@arr[2]\n";
```

the output is:

> swatkats
>   popeye
>   avengers

but expected output:

> Tbone Razer
>   olive bluto pope
>   ironman hulk blackwidow cap

What am I doing wrong here?

Ps: How do you add another array to hash in the above snippet.

Comment: Have you read [the official documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html#HASHES-OF-ARRAYS) on this subject?

Comment: I just did that now! :) @MattJacob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output you are looking for would be generated with:

```
%HoA = (
    swatkats => [ "Tbone", "Razer" ],
    popeye   => [ "Olive", "bluto", "pope" ],
    avengers => [ "ironman", "hulk", "Blackwidow", "cap"]);
@arr = keys %HoA;
print join(' ', @{$HoA{$arr[0]}}). "\n";
print join(' ', @{$HoA{$arr[1]}}). "\n";
print join(' ', @{$HoA{$arr[2]}}). "\n";
```

Adding another entry is done by:

```
$HoA{'new entry'} = [ 1, 2 , 4 ];
```

HTH
George

Comment: can you please explain why this syntax `join(' ', @{$HoA{$arr[0]}}). "\n"; ?`  @Georg Mavridis

Comment: $arr[0] is the first entry of your Array, teh first key of the hash,

$HoA{$arr[0]} ist the value corresponding to the first key the Anonymous Array [..] (or as it is easier for me to compute, the reference to this Array)

@{$HoA{$arr[0]}} dereferences the Anyonmous Array into a list which is joined there.



$arr[0]

Answer (score 1):

The output you are  getting because you have used `keys` keyword which iterates the keys of a hash. You can use `values` keyword to iterates the values:

```
my %HoA = (
    swatkats => [ "Tbone", "Razer" ],
    popeye => [ "Olive", "bluto", "pope" ],
    avengers => [ "ironman", "hulk", "Blackwidow","cap"]
);

foreach my $value (values %HoA)
{
    print join(' ', @$value), "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
ironman hulk Blackwidow cap
Olive bluto pope
Tbone Razer
```